# Bootstrap Datepicker - Months and Years Only

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datepicker and my code is like following, Demo of the code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2sW/)

```
<div class="input-append date" id="datepicker" data-date="02-2012" 
     data-date-format="mm-yyyy">

 <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date" >    
 <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>      
</div>      


$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        viewMode: 'years',
         format: 'mm-yyyy'
    });
```

The above code is working fine, but what I am trying to do is allow users pick months and years only.

Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: I'd just use two select boxes... it would make a lot more sense than using a calendar widget, and trying to hide the actual calendar.

Comment: Would you still use two select boxes even if you had an option like this http://jsfiddle.net/Kz2sW/1/ ? :)

Answer (score 315, accepted):

How about this :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

Reference : [Datepicker for Bootstrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

---

For version 1.2.0 and newer, `viewMode` has changed to `startView`, so use:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    startView: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

Also see [the documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#startdate).

Comment: Thanks but I had to replace `format: " mm"` with `format: "mm-yyyy"` . Its working now :)

Comment: It doesn't show the `-` between months and years if you keep a space before `mm-yyyy` in `format: " mm-yyyy",`, could you please edit your answer again?

Comment: I don't think viewMode is a valid option as per the documentation. But the other options allowed the required display to work.

Comment: Is there any option for autoclose?

Answer (score 8):

Notice that in the version of 1.2.0 the `viewMode` has changed to `startView`.

eg:

```
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  startView: 1,
  minViewMode: 1
});
```

http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=component&format=yyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=2&minViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&language=zh-CN&orientation=auto&autoclose=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

Answer (score 4):

I'm using version 2(supports both bootstrap v2 and v3) and for me this works:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "year", 
    minView: "year"
});
```

Comment: change `minView` to `minViewMode`

Answer (score 3):

For the latest `bootstrap-datepicker` (1.4.0 at the time of writing), you need to use this:

```
$('#myDatepicker').datepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "year", 
    minViewMode: "months"
})
```

Source: [*Bootstrap Datepicker Options*](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html)

Comment: on click of month in bootstrap, it is showing the date and then entering text in mm/yy format

Answer (score 1):

I am using bootstrap calender for future date not allow with allow change in months & year only..

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
        j(function () {
            j(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" }).val()
        });

        j(function () {
            j(".Futuredatenotallowed").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                maxDate: 0,
                changeYear: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
                language: "tr"
            }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).blur();
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            }).val()
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have to add only `minViewMode: "months"` in your datepicker function.

Answer (score 1):

To view the months of the current year, and only the months, use this format - it only takes the months of that year. It can also be restricted so that a certain number of months is displayed.

```
<input class="form-control" id="txtDateMMyyyy"  autocomplete="off" required readonly/>

<script>
('#txtDateMMyyyy').datetimepicker({
    format: "mm/yyyy",
    startView: "year",
    minView: "year"
}).datetimepicker("setDate", new Date());
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: Se agrego una pequeña descripcion de lo que hace el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you want to get only year this will help you

```
  $('.date-own').datepicker({
     minViewMode: 2,
     format: 'yyyy'
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but its working with datepicker 1.9.0. It shows only month and year after selecting you will get only Month and Year in your input

```
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker form-control" />

$(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    autoclose: true,
minViewMode: 1,
format: 'mm-yyyy',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score -1):

Why not call the `$('.input-group.date').datepicker("remove");` when the select statement is changed then set your datepicker view then call the `$('.input-group.date').datepicker("update");`