# How to change bootstrap datepicker to look like Jquery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using [bootstrap datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker) in my project but client wants easy selection for years like [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year) where user can select years from drop down.

I dont want to change my library because I have used it in so many places is there any easiest way to change the year/month selection within bootstrap datepicker.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974394/bootstrap-datepicker-months-and-years-only

Comment: @PawanLakhara No I want date as well, but year selection needs to be dropdown, just like jquery UI.

Comment: check this link http://www.daterangepicker.com/   Single Date Picker with change month and year