# input type="month" replacement for Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, input

Currently, Firefox doesn't support HTML5 `<input type="month">`. Other major browsers support it (it allows selection of year and month). What is the best custom JavaScript replacement for it in Firefox?

Answer (score -12, accepted):

Latest Firefox supports that, older versions not.
You can use Bootstrap Datepicker which is extremly powerful, see [here](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [here](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Comment: It doesn't, I have Firefox Nightly 62.0a1 (2018-05-20) and there is no support. It also says the same here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888320

Comment: Have you try the bootstrap datepicker I suggested?

Comment: Yes and it seems the best solution because it supports month-year selection natively. Here is another answear where I found how to configure it for month-year only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974394/bootstrap-datepicker-months-and-years-only
Thanks!

Comment: Not even on Firefox v87.0 except being used as though it is `type="text"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `jQuery UI` datepicker()

```js
$(() => {
  $('#date').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<input id='date'>
```