# datepicker does not display months but days

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have a problem with the datepicker. I see the days and not only the months I mean instead of having this :

[image: datepicker]

I get this :

[image: datepicker]

Here is my code :

```
 <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

and here is the js :

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "mm-yyyy",
    viewMode: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months"
});
```

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: No because I mean I want the following format : `"mm-yyyy"` instead of "`dd-mm-yyyy," `but when I set the format  `"mm-yyyy"` it is like I set the format  `"dd-mm-yyyy"`

Comment: Rename the datepicker id I think datepicker already implemented by this id. write #datepicker-month instead of #datepicker

Comment: It changes nothing :/

Comment: you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14974623/9042437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#datepicker-month").datepicker( {
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        viewMode: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="datepicker-month" />
```

Comment: It changes nothing :/

Comment: Please try with the above bootstrap-datepicker libraries or you can download it  https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: @Peter *"I tried but without any effects"* even after a provided working snippet makes your comment pretty strange.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

```
$('#you-date-picker-element').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    orientation: 'left',
    container: '.your-date-picker-container',
    format: 'M-yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
    startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate(new Date(selected.date.valueOf())));
    $('#your-field-name').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same problem :/

Comment: did you add `minViewMode`. This will show month only in datepicker. Check this link. https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#minviewmode